# iptables configuration to allow access from another subnet

Tags: iptables, subnet

I'm trying to allow ssh access to a computer behind a firewall from a computer in another subnet. The computer behind the firewall is at 10.66.1.1/255.255.0.0, while the other computer is at 10.99.1.1/255.0.0.0.

I tried to add the following rule to iptables, but I still cannot access the firewalled computer.

```
iptables --append INPUT --match tcp --protocol tcp --src 10.99.1.1 --sport 22 --dst 10.66.1.1 --dport 22 --jump ACCEPT
```

Comment: That rule seems like it is close, but iptables rules are processed in order.  It is impossible for us to know if it will work without knowing the rest of your rules.  If this rule is added after an explicit drop, then it wouldn't do anything.  Also, without more details about your network, I am not sure if you are going o the right chain.  IE, are you sure you should be on INPUT and not forward?  Please add more details.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `--sport 22`

The source port is random.

see explanation in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616527/are-ssh-destination-and-source-ports-identical-symmetric-ports

Answer (score 2):

**Solution :**

Delete the source port in your rule, you will have a rule like :

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.99.1.1 -d 10.66.1.1 -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

**Explanations:**

First we will assume that there is no routing problem but only firewall configuration.

The computer 10.99.1.1 (client) want to open a SSH session on the 10.66.1.1 (server).

The server must:

- Have an operational & configured ssh server
- Have its firewall open for SSH port (22 by default) :

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.99.1.1 -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

The intermediate firewall should have a iptable rule like :

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.99.1.1 -d 10.66.1.1 -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

The error you have committed is to specify the source port. Only the destination port on the server is required.

The client do not use the 22 port as source port for the SSH connection. The client ask the server for a new ssh session on the port 22 but use a local random port.

You can check that with the `netstat -taupenl|grep ':22'` , you should see at leat :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          11242       540/sshd
tcp        0      0 ip.server:22        ip.client:35332    ESTABLISHED 0          570915      12917/0
```

The first line matche the listening port of the ssh server, the second line match the current ssh connection with the client you can see the used ports, 22 for the server, 35332 for the client.

`[Client]:35332  <---->  [Server]:22`

As the client ports are used randomly depending on the availability on the client you should not specify the source port.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the mask bits:

```
iptables --append INPUT --match tcp --protocol tcp --src 10.99.1.0/8 --dport 22 --jump ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

If the subnet masks are really like you describe in your post, especially `10.99.1.1/255.0.0.0`, you cannot do anything with IPTables about this.

The subnet mask of `255.0.0.0` tells the computer that every IP address beginning with `10.` is in the same L2 broadcast domain as the computer itself. This means that `10.99.1.1` will try to send all packets destined to `10.66.1.1` directly on the same network, without trying any routing.

Meanwhile, since `10.66.1.1` has netmask `255.255.0.0`, the packets from that computer will be routed to `10.99.1.1`.

You need to fix your routing first.

Comment: so if I change the subnet masks to both be 255.255.0.0, would iptables be able to do the routing?

Comment: IPTables does not do routing, Linux kernel does routing. Changing subnet mask fixes that part, but then there can be other issues in your setup.